# C++ Nested class (Make friend outer member function)?

Tags: c++, class, nested, friend

My code:

```
class Controller {

private:
    class ControllerMetals {
        private:
            int m_size;
            Metals * m_metals;
        public:
            ControllerMetals();
            Metals & getMetals() const;
            int getSize() const;
            void setSize(int size) { m_size = size; }
            void init();
            void show();
            void erase();
        friend void Controller::start(ControllerMetals & c); // why don't work ?
    };

private:
     ControllerMetals * controlMetals;

public:
    void start(ControllerMetals & c);
    ControllerMetals * getControlMetals() const;
    Controller();

};
```

I want to make a void start to have access private member in ControllerMetals class. Why friend statements don't work ?

Comment: Since ControllerMetals is private inside of Controller, why not make everything public in ControllerMetals?  Obviously the nested private class is tightly coupled with the outer class.

Comment: I have a task and I must declare my inner class as private member of outer class. And all member must be private.

Comment: `Controller::start` doesn't exist when you friend it. You can declare a datatype when you friend it but I don't think you can with a function. Forward declare `ControllerMetals` so you can refer to it and then formally define it after the functions. Why the hell didn't I just make an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

Member functions have to be declared before you can `friend` them. `friend` has a built-in forward declaration for a data type, but not for members of that data type.

## Solution

Personally I agree with Eljay's comment, make everything in `ControllerMetals` `public` because it is already hidden by `Controller`, but if the assignment says no, do what you have to do to pass the course.

Simple solution:

You `friend` the whole `Controller` class to get the members, but this might be too broad.

More complicated, tighter-grained solution:

More stuff around so that the required member function is declared before `ControllerMetals`. You can get away with this because the `start` only needs a declaration of `ControllerMetals` in order to take references to it.

```
class Controller {

    class ControllerMetals; // forward declare to make available for referencing
public:
    void start(ControllerMetals & c); // start now known. Can friend
    ControllerMetals * getControlMetals() const;
    Controller();

private:
    // now we can fully define ControllerMetals
    class ControllerMetals {
        private:
            int m_size;
            Metals * m_metals;
        public:
            ControllerMetals();
            Metals & getMetals() const;
            int getSize() const;
            void setSize(int size) { m_size = size; }
            void init(); // why is this not done in the constructor?
            void show();
            void erase();
        friend void Controller::start(ControllerMetals & c); // now works
    };
     ControllerMetals * controlMetals;


};
```